# Reload grid (not the store) in extjs4

Tags: grid, extjs4, reload

I need to switch between these two grids whit pressing of a button:
[image] [image]
I don't need to re'load.() the store because the data is the same for both grids, and I just make some calculations for displaying data.
Do you know how can I reload the grid ?  (using card is not a option)

Comment: Have you tried grid.reconfigure?

Comment: Can you add your comment as a answer so I can vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the [reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) method.